# eigenvector and eigenvalues of $T(p)=\hat{p}$ where $\hat{p}=p(t+1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

On $\mathcal{P}^3\{\mathbb{R}\}$ define T by $T(p) = \hat{p}$ where $\hat{p} = p(t+1)$ Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of T.

I dont understand how to transform the $\hat{p}$ into the T matrix. What would the matrix look like and why?

Comment: Let $p(t)=a+bt+ct^{2}+dt^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R})$, so $T(p(t))=p(t+1)=a+b(t+1)+c(t+1)^{2}+d(t+1)^{3}$. Now, let $\beta=\{1,x,x^{2},x^{3}\}$be a basis for $P_{3}(\mathbb{R})$. Can you continue with that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(t):=a+bt+ct^{2}+dt^{3}\in P_{3}(\mathbb{R})$, so $$T(p(t))=p(t+1)=a+b(t+1)+c(t+1)^{2}+d(t+1)^{3}.$$Now, let $\beta=\{1,x,x^{2},x^{3}\}$be a basis for $P_{3}(\mathbb{R})$.

1. Now you can calculate $[T]_{\beta}$.
2. You can calculate eigenvalues $\lambda$'s of $[T]_{\beta}$, using $p(\lambda)=det(A-\lambda I)=0.$
3. You can calculate eigenvectors using $E_{\lambda}=Nuc(A-\lambda I)$.
4. You need to remember that coordinates for each  eigenvectors of $T$ are the eigenvectors of $[T]_{\beta}$. This means  $v_{i} \iff [v_{i}]$.